# Add weekend values to Monday SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, date, count, sum

I am working in mySQL and I currently have a count of total orders by day, but I would like to add Saturday and Sunday orders to Monday then remove Saturday and Sunday values. I have done some research on this but I cannot seem to find anything similar to what I am trying to do.

My current data table looks like this:

```
Date      | Daily Count
8-6-2020         25
8-7-2020         82
8-8-2020         24
8-9-2020         33
8-10-2020        18
8-11-2020        10
8-12-2020        25
8-13-2020        15
```

I need it to look something like this:

```
Date      | Daily Count
8-6-2020         25
8-7-2020         82
8-10-2020        75
8-11-2020        10
8-12-2020        25
8-13-2020        15
```

In this one the Daily counts for the 8th and 9th are added to the 10th, then removed, because they are weekend days. Thank you in advance for your help!

Comment: What have you tried so far? Where are you stuck?

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider using a `case` expression to adjust the date:

```
select 
    case weekday(date)
        when 5 then date + interval 2 day
        when 6 then date + interval 1 day
        else date
    end as new_date,
    sum(daily_count) as daily_count
from mytable
group by new_date
```